# wp_nav_menu work in functions.php but not in the theme

Tags: functions, theme-development, menus

I use `wp_nav_menu` with this code in `functions.php`:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'sidebar_menu' => 'Sidebar menu',
    'topmenu' => 'topmenu',
) );

$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'topmenu'
);
wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

This code works. The menu will show up before everything else in the theme. Now I want to menu inside my `header.php` for example and I try to move the code there:

```
$args = array(
    'theme_location' => 'topmenu'
);
wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

I expected the code to work here as well but it does not. The menu is empty. The function `register_nav_menus` is still in the `functions.php`. The `header.php` is loaded correctly.

**The code below returns true in the `header.php`**

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'topmenu' ) ) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Why does the menu show up empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a `pre_get_posts`. What I missed was this:

```
&& $wp_query->is_main_query()
```

This prevents the `pre_get_posts` to run on the menu query.

**Full code**

```
add_action("pre_get_posts", "custom_front_page");
function custom_front_page( $wp_query ){
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( is_front_page() && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
        $wp_query->set('post_type', 'produkt');
        $wp_query->set('page_id', ''); 

        $wp_query->is_page = 0;
        $wp_query->is_singular = 0;
        $wp_query->is_post_type_archive = 1;
        $wp_query->is_archive = 1;
    }
}
```